# What is the bigint equivalent in dynamics AX?

Tags: int, x++, axapta, bigint

I  need to use a datatype to store integer value but I need the one equivalent to BigInt. Is there any in Dynamics AX?

Answer (score 5):

To define a 64-bit integer variable in X++, use `int64`.

[Integers AX 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa851966.aspx)

[Integers AX 2009](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa851966%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)